# Google Play prevents publishing updated APK and forces declaring unused permission

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-permissions

I'm unable to publish an APK update: Google Play says the app does not respect the permission rules.

Also, in the permission declaration form, it forces to check at least one SMS or CALL LOG related permission, even though the app does not request any SMS or CALL LOG related permission. It's been removed from the manifest several APK ago.

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: probably one of the libraries uses it?

Comment: I need help from other developers to update an app. Where should I go if not on stackoverflow @Tim Castelijns ?

Comment: I don't know, maybe ask the guys who run the play store

Comment: I've checked the app merged manifest and no trace of SMS or CALL LOG permission @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @TimCastelijns I already asked the Google Play support, but I need to release an update pretty quickly, and I think stackoverflow is an appropriate place to request help for solving "real life" problem of developers

Comment: @TimCastelijns This isn't a question about the policy, its about how to remove the permission.  That makes it an allowable question.  Asking why the policy exists or what policy a piece of code breaks would be unallowed.  And the answer here is you probably picked it up via dependency.

Comment: not really. He said that the permission is not present in the merged manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from having other active APKs using SMS or CALL LOG related permissions in other release tracks such as Internal Testing, Alpha, Beta

To solve the issue, you need to get rid of all the old artifacts and replace them with your new build in all the release tracks (Internal Testing, Alpha, Beta, Production), even if you won’t end up using these release tracks.

You can see all your active APKs across all release tracks in Google Play's console from the Artefact Library menu:

[image]

You can find more infos about the solution here:
https://proandroiddev.com/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690

Thanks a lot to @BapusahebPatil for this article

EDIT: There is an open issue related to this on Google issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117486314